# How to approach this circular motion question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A circular track has several concentric rings where people can run at their leisure. Phil runs on the outermost track with radius $r_P$ and Annie runs on an inner track with radius $r_A$ = $0.8*r_P$. The runners start side by side along a radial line, and run at the same speed in the counterclockwise direction. How many revolutions has Annie made when Annie's and Phil's velocity vectors point in opposite directions for the first time?

I'm stuck on how to approach this question. I know that Annie's smaller radius will translate into more revolutions/unit time and that her velocity vector  $v_A$ will be equal to $-v_P$. What equations should I be using?

Answer (score 5):

You will wanna use the equations for $\theta$

$\theta_p = \dfrac {v}{r_p} t $

$\theta_a = \dfrac {v}{r_a} t $

and the time when the vectors are opposite would be

$\theta_a = \theta_p + \pi$